# Button.Click не работает в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Кнопка перестает нажиматься, когда я устанавливаю (для скролла в ScrollViewer при нажатии мыши) PreviewMouseMove, PreviewMouseWheel, PreviewMouseDown, PreviewMouseUp. Что делать?
Решение не нашел. Перепробовал уже все. Если я уберу эти PreviewMouse*, то кнопка работает без всяких проблем. Кнопка - btnSelectServer.

```
<ScrollViewer 
            x:Name="scrollViewer"
            Background="Transparent"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0,0,0,240"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Height="150"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            PreviewMouseMove="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseMove"
            PreviewMouseWheel="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"
            PreviewMouseDown="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
            PreviewMouseUp="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
            <ItemsControl
                x:Name="serversList"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Server}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Margin="5" Width="210" Height="40">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/server_bg.png"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                <Label x:Name="serverName" FontSize="12" Content="{Binding serverName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Width="120" Height="30" Margin="40,10,50,10" />
                                <Button 
                                    x:Name="btnSelectServer" 
                                    Width="30" Height="30" 
                                    Margin="170,0,0,0"
                                    Click="btnSelectServer_Click"
                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.919,1.064"
                                    Cursor="Hand"
                                    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                    Foreground="{x:Null}">
                                    <Button.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/server_play.png"/>
                                    </Button.Background>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147131/discussion-on-question-by-stepdev-button-click----wpf); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.